# Append new Data to JSON Data

Tags: android, json

I am somewhat new to JSON and I wanted to write a simple method that would append a data to my JSON instead of creating new JSON Object.

Here is my JSON Code:

```
public static JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
public static String toJSON(params) {

    try {

        jsonObj.put("Timestamp", timestamp); 
        jsonObj.put("Package Name", packageName);
        jsonObj.put("Package Label", packageLabel);
        jsonObj.put("Permissions Requested at Once", permissionReqOnce);
        jsonObj.put("Permission Group", permGroup);
        jsonObj.put("Accept or Deny", acceptDeny);

        return jsonObj.toString();

    }
    catch(JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, when I call it like this,

```
toJSON("data0", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data");
toJSON("data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1");
Log.d("JSON", FileHandle.jsonObj.toString());
```

it only returns me the last passed data:

```
{"Timestamp":"data1","Package Name":"data1","Package Label":"data1","Permissions Requested at Once":"data1","Permission Group":"data1","Accept or Deny":"data1"}
```

**What I want is:**

```
[
 {
   "Timestamp": "data0",
   "Package Name": "data",
   "Package Label": "data",
   "Permissions Requested at Once": "data",
   "Permission Group": "data",
   "Accept or Deny": "data",
 },
 {
   "Timestamp": "data1",
   "Package Name": "data1",
   "Package Label": "data1",
   "Permissions Requested at Once": "data1",
   "Permission Group": "data1",
   "Accept or Deny": "data1",
 }
]
```

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSONArray` as root container instead of `JSONObject`

During every call, Create new `JSONObject` and put it inside `root` `JSONArray`

Then use

```
// our root JSONArray to store JSONObject 
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

public static String toJSON(params) {
    // inner JSONObject
    JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject();         
    try {
        // Here we convert Java Object to JSON
        jsonObj1.put("Timestamp", timestamp); // Set the first name/pair
        jsonObj1.put("Package Name", packageName);
        jsonObj1.put("Package Label", packageLabel);
        jsonObj1.put("Permissions Requested at Once", permissionReqOnce);
        jsonObj1.put("Permission Group", permGroup);
        jsonObj1.put("Accept or Deny", acceptDeny);
        jsonArr.put(jsonObj1);
        // return string form of collected data so far as jsonarray
        return jsonArr.toString();

    }
    catch(JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Jeet.Deir i am glad that i could help , happy coding :)